# How to add timestamps to Java Applet console

Tags: java, logging, console, applet, timestamp

I need to time the Applet plugin startup time, and also the startup time of a specific Applet.

I have enabled debugging and tracing in the Java preferences, but the log and trace have no timestamps.

How can I enable them?

EDIT: I didn't develop this Applet, nor do I have access to the source code.

Comment: Use a logger (like log4j)

Comment: It isn't an Applet that I've developed, or have access to the source code for.